# Can't find proguard-rules.pro in my flutter app

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, proguard

I keep getting the error message "Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'."

According to stackoverflow question [transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454128/transformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelease-failed) I need to just add the following code to my proguard-rules.pro:

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

Where do I find this proguard-rules.pro file? Do i need to create it myself and if so, whereabouts should I put in my app directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, we will enable shrinking in the build file. Find `build.gradle` file which sits inside `/android/app/` folder and add lines in bold

```
android {

    ...

    buildTypes {

        release {
            
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug     
            //add everything below
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 

        }
    }
}
```

Next, we will create a configuration that will preserve the entire Flutter wrapper code. Create `/android/app/proguard-rules.pro` file and insert inside:

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

DONE!

Comment: i did your solution but got error i dont know why  Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_czlcicqqc0apz0tggwztw1w16.android() is applicable for argument types:

Comment: when i remove useProguard true  line then it work fine

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks, but remove 'useProguard true'