# Gradle Job failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Problem "Generating a Signed APK". When I want to test my App on a Device or Emulator everything is fine, but when I want to deploy for App Store I get this Error but I can't fix them.

What is the Problem?

Elias

[image]

[image]

[image]

Android Monitor Log:

```
08-26 16:08:38.335 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
08-26 16:08:38.336 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
08-26 16:08:38.336 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 14
08-26 16:08:38.348 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=am,name=ad_exposure(_xa),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, exposure_time(_xt)=60450}]
08-26 16:08:38.352 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:38.353 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: ad_exposure(_xa), 66
08-26 16:08:38.354 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco', name='ad_exposure(_xa)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, exposure_time(_xt)=60450}]}
08-26 16:08:38.360 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 963034
08-26 16:08:38.365 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
08-26 16:08:38.368 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:38.370 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
08-26 16:08:38.371 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 23
08-26 16:08:39.598 14921-9534/? D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_activeview(_aa), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, ad_event_id(_aeid)=6246921737258766336}]
08-26 16:08:39.631 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=am,name=ad_activeview(_aa),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, ad_event_id(_aeid)=6246921737258766336}]
08-26 16:08:39.641 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: ad_activeview(_aa), 74
08-26 16:08:39.642 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco', name='ad_activeview(_aa)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, ad_event_id(_aeid)=6246921737258766336}]}
08-26 16:08:39.648 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 961746
08-26 16:08:39.650 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
08-26 16:08:39.650 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
08-26 16:08:39.651 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 20
08-26 16:08:39.804 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:39.882 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:39.902 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:39.916 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:39.939 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:39.949 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:39.965 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:39.982 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:39.999 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:40.016 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:40.031 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:40.048 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:40.065 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:40.083 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:40.103 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:40.122 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:40.145 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:40.160 14921-14921/? W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
08-26 16:08:44.630 14921-9534/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
08-26 16:08:51.584 1695-1965/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dbda620: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dbf1480)

                                                --------- beginning of system
08-26 16:08:51.592 1608-1620/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10804000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity} from uid 10027 on display 0
08-26 16:08:51.594 1358-1379/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4380682 , only wrote 4380480
08-26 16:08:51.603 14921-9534/? V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1644698
08-26 16:08:51.603 14921-9534/? V/FA: Using measurement service
08-26 16:08:51.603 14921-9534/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
08-26 16:08:51.607 14921-9534/? V/FA: Activity paused, time: 6828674
08-26 16:08:51.609 14921-9534/? D/FA: Logging event (FE): adunit_exposure(_xu), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, ad_unit_id(_ai)=ca-app-pub-3283595098772549/2523586914, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, exposure_time(_xt)=13317}]
08-26 16:08:51.617 14921-9534/? V/FA: Using measurement service
08-26 16:08:51.617 14921-9534/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-26 16:08:51.618 14921-9534/? D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_exposure(_xa), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, exposure_time(_xt)=13317}]
08-26 16:08:51.623 1304-1883/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 4784128
08-26 16:08:51.625 14921-9534/? V/FA: Using measurement service
08-26 16:08:51.625 14921-9534/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-26 16:08:51.625 14921-9534/? D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1644698, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210}]

                                      [ 08-26 16:08:51.631  1608: 1620 D/         ]
                                      HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x8e5ff480, tid 1620
08-26 16:08:51.634 14921-9534/? V/FA: Using measurement service
08-26 16:08:51.634 14921-9534/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-26 16:08:51.634 14921-9534/? V/FA: Not logging ad unit exposure. No active activity
08-26 16:08:51.634 14921-9534/? V/FA: Not logging ad exposure. No active activity
08-26 16:08:51.634 14921-9534/? D/FA: Connected to remote service
08-26 16:08:51.634 14921-9534/? V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
08-26 16:08:51.647 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=am,name=adunit_exposure(_xu),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, ad_unit_id(_ai)=ca-app-pub-3283595098772549/2523586914, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, exposure_time(_xt)=13317}]
08-26 16:08:51.693 14921-16110/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e679c60: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9e678e10)
08-26 16:08:51.696 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: adunit_exposure(_xu), 112
08-26 16:08:51.696 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco', name='adunit_exposure(_xu)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, ad_unit_id(_ai)=ca-app-pub-3283595098772549/2523586914, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, exposure_time(_xt)=13317}]}
08-26 16:08:51.698 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 949697
08-26 16:08:51.699 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
08-26 16:08:51.699 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
08-26 16:08:51.700 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 53
08-26 16:08:51.708 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=am,name=ad_exposure(_xa),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, exposure_time(_xt)=13317}]
08-26 16:08:51.717 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: ad_exposure(_xa), 65
08-26 16:08:51.718 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco', name='ad_exposure(_xa)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210, exposure_time(_xt)=13317}]}
08-26 16:08:51.721 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 949673
08-26 16:08:51.722 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
08-26 16:08:51.723 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
08-26 16:08:51.724 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 16
08-26 16:08:51.739 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=user_engagement(_e),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1644698, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210}]
08-26 16:08:51.741 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: user_engagement(_e), 68
08-26 16:08:51.741 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco', name='user_engagement(_e)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1644698, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=229789555992104210}]}
08-26 16:08:51.744 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 949650
08-26 16:08:51.746 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
08-26 16:08:51.746 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with AlarmManager
08-26 16:08:51.747 2380-9545/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 8
08-26 16:08:51.943 1695-1965/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dbda620: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dbf1480)
08-26 16:08:52.039 1695-1965/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dbda620: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dbf1480)
08-26 16:08:52.070 1695-1965/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dbda620: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dbf1480)
08-26 16:08:52.146 1304-1372/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 1044480
08-26 16:08:52.250 1695-1965/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dbda620: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dbf1480)
08-26 16:08:52.550 1695-1965/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dbda620: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dbf1480)
08-26 16:08:53.006 1608-2147/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 2851:com.google.android.gms.unstable/u0a14 (adj 906): empty for 2208s
08-26 16:08:53.006 1608-2147/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 3544:com.android.defcontainer/u0a8 (adj 906): empty for 2210s
08-26 16:08:53.006 1608-2147/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 14921:adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco/u0a80 (adj 902): remove task
08-26 16:08:53.009 1608-1679/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 3544
08-26 16:08:53.025 1608-1880/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher3/.Launcher} from uid 10027 on display 0
08-26 16:08:53.071 1608-2147/? D/ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ id=25, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ], android.os.BinderProxy@cd18842)
08-26 16:08:53.071 1608-1868/? D/ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ id=26, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ], android.os.BinderProxy@1c75053)
08-26 16:08:53.072 1608-1619/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 3
08-26 16:08:53.078 1608-1669/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=25, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
08-26 16:08:53.079 1608-2149/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 14921
08-26 16:08:53.079 1608-1669/? E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=26, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
08-26 16:08:53.084 1608-1654/? W/InputDispatcher: channel 'ff6b22 adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco/adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
08-26 16:08:53.084 1608-1654/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'ff6b22 adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco/adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-26 16:08:53.085 1695-1965/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dbda620: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dbf1480)
08-26 16:08:53.203 1695-1965/? D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x8efa8b80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x8aeb9370
08-26 16:08:53.231 1608-1679/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{ff6b22 u0 adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco/adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco.MainActivity}
08-26 16:08:53.231 1608-1679/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'ff6b22 adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco/adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco.MainActivity (server)'
08-26 16:08:53.231 1608-1679/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco/adl.solutions.com.shishatobacco.MainActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1780 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:688 <bottom of call stack> 
08-26 16:08:53.233 1608-2148/? W/art: Long monitor contention with owner android.display (1631) at void com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(long)(WindowAnimator.java:138) waiters=3 in void com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.statusBarVisibilityChanged(int) for 132ms
08-26 16:08:53.247 1608-2035/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 2851
08-26 16:08:53.247 1608-1685/? W/art: Long monitor contention with owner Binder:1608_A (2149) at void com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient.binderDied()(ActivityManagerService.java:1459) waiters=5 in void com.android.server.am.TaskPersister.writeTaskIdsFiles() for 108ms
08-26 16:08:53.253 2132-2249/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9d7ab680: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9db97de0)
08-26 16:08:53.385 1608-1631/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.recents.RecentsActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:427 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateAppWindowsLocked:176 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:678 
08-26 16:08:53.786 2132-2249/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
08-26 16:08:54.839 1358-1379/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4536280 , only wrote 4536000
08-26 16:08:54.840 1358-1379/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4536003 , only wrote 4536000
08-26 16:08:54.856 1358-1379/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4536768 , only wrote 4536720
08-26 16:08:55.106 1358-1379/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4548741 , only wrote 4546080
08-26 16:08:55.106 1358-1379/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4546084 , only wrote 4546080
08-26 16:08:55.155 1358-1379/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4548430 , only wrote 4546800
08-26 16:08:55.982 1358-1380/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 4625172 , only wrote 4586400
08-26 16:09:00.030 1695-1965/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9dbda620: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9dbf1480)
08-26 16:09:15.901 9795-9795/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
08-26 16:09:15.909 1608-2147/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 9795:com.google.android.gms.unstable/u0a14 for service com.google.android.gms/.droidguard.DroidGuardService
08-26 16:09:15.918 9795-9795/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86
08-26 16:09:15.918 9795-9802/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:09:15.918 9795-9802/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:09:15.925 9795-9795/? I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
08-26 16:09:15.939 9795-9795/? V/NativeCrypto: Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 259 native methods...
08-26 16:09:15.947 9795-9795/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
08-26 16:09:15.947 9795-9795/? I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
08-26 16:09:16.045 1364-1387/? D/WVCdm: Instantiating CDM.
08-26 16:09:16.046 1364-1364/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::OpenSession
08-26 16:09:16.046 1364-1364/? I/WVCdm: Level3 Library 4464 Mar 30 2016 13:26:29
08-26 16:09:16.046 1364-1364/? W/WVCdm: Could not load liboemcrypto.so. Falling back to L3.  dlopen failed: library "liboemcrypto.so" not found
08-26 16:09:16.048 1364-1364/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::QueryKeyControlInfo
08-26 16:09:16.048 1364-5052/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::GenerateKeyRequest
08-26 16:09:16.049 1364-5052/? D/WVCdm: PrepareKeyRequest: nonce=662841306
08-26 16:09:16.095 1364-3243/? I/WVCdm: CdmEngine::CloseSession
08-26 16:09:16.258 9823-9823/? W/dex2oat: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
08-26 16:09:16.258 9823-9823/? W/dex2oat: Mismatch between dex2oat instruction set features (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt) and those of dex2oat executable (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt) for the command line:
08-26 16:09:16.258 9823-9823/? W/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg & --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_fb/f.apk --oat-fd=49 --oat-location=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_fb/f.dex --compiler-filter=speed
08-26 16:09:16.258 9823-9823/? I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --dex-file=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_fb/f.apk --oat-fd=49 --oat-location=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_fb/f.dex --compiler-filter=speed
08-26 16:09:16.304 9823-9823/? I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 46.321ms (threads: 2) arena alloc=195KB (200608B) java alloc=76KB (78168B) native alloc=960KB (983640B) free=1599KB (1637800B)
08-26 16:09:16.306 9795-9808/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 

                                         [ 08-26 16:09:16.311  9795: 9808 D/         ]
                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x87ff9cc0, tid 9808
08-26 16:09:16.318 9795-9808/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xad0868c0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
08-26 16:09:16.336 9795-9808/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xad0868c0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x87ff29b0)
08-26 16:09:16.337 9795-9808/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
08-26 16:09:16.337 9795-9808/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
08-26 16:09:16.337 9795-9808/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
08-26 16:09:16.366 9795-9808/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xad086bc0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
08-26 16:09:16.372 9795-9808/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xad086bc0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x87ff29b0)
08-26 16:09:16.372 9795-9808/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
08-26 16:09:16.372 9795-9808/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
08-26 16:09:16.372 9795-9808/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
08-26 16:09:16.468 9795-9795/? W/Binder:9795_2: type=1400 audit(0.0:17): avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="tmpfs" ino=4003 scontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
08-26 16:09:16.535 2050-2462/? W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout:
08-26 16:09:16.535 2050-2462/? W/Conscrypt:    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-26 16:09:16.535 2050-2462/? W/Conscrypt:    yid.a(:com.google.android.gms:58)
08-26 16:09:16.576 2050-2462/? W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout:
08-26 16:09:16.576 2050-2462/? W/Conscrypt:    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-26 16:09:16.576 2050-2462/? W/Conscrypt:    yid.a(:com.google.android.gms:58)
08-26 16:09:16.612 2050-2462/? W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
                                          java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
                                              at etz.a(:com.google.android.gms:10)
                                              at etz.a(:com.google.android.gms:61)
                                              at etx.a(:com.google.android.gms:7)
                                              at ett.a(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                              at ets.a(:com.google.android.gms:9)
                                              at com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.b(:com.google.android.gms:6)
                                              at eal.call(:com.google.android.gms:2)
                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                              at mge.run(:com.google.android.gms:24)
                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                              at mlf.run(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
08-26 16:11:34.243 2380-2387/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.243 2380-2387/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.243 1608-1612/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.243 1608-1612/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.243 16699-16706/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.243 16699-16706/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.243 1695-1709/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.243 1695-1709/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.243 9220-9227/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.243 9220-9227/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.243 1801-1808/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.243 1801-1808/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.243 9180-9198/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.243 2008-2015/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.243 9180-9198/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.243 2008-2015/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.243 2050-2057/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.243 2050-2057/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.244 2087-2094/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.244 2087-2094/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.244 9795-9802/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.244 2132-2140/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.244 9795-9802/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.244 2132-2140/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.244 16970-16977/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.244 16970-16977/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.244 1688-1705/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.244 1688-1705/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.244 16787-16794/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.244 16787-16794/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.244 5088-5095/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.244 5088-5095/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:11:34.244 5104-5111/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-26 16:11:34.244 5104-5111/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-26 16:14:41.345 1608-1621/system_process I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
08-26 16:15:02.938 1608-1665/system_process D/WifiNative-HAL: Failing getSupportedFeatureset because HAL isn't started
08-26 16:15:02.938 1608-1627/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
08-26 16:15:02.939 1608-1627/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
08-26 16:15:02.942 1608-1627/system_process E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
08-26 16:15:02.942 1608-1627/system_process E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
08-26 16:15:02.942 1608-1627/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
08-26 16:16:00.003 1608-1622/system_process I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 1ms
08-26 16:16:00.005 1608-1622/system_process I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 2ms
```

Comment: Please post your log, android monitor..

Comment: Why Android Monitor Log?

Comment: It shows more info why the build failed

Comment: txt.do/d64de Here is the Link to my Log.

Comment: Edit your question and provide it there.

Comment: Had to remove about 4000 Chars because of limit

Comment: You could have just posted the error - Invalid device key response

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/201

Comment: Thanks for the help but still now fix. Still the same error.

Comment: What's your gradle version and compileSDK? And check if all your libraries are up to date

Comment: gradle Version: 4.0 and compileSDK 26 and all "com.android.support" are on 26.0.0-alpha1

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solutions, maybe helpfully for other Developers getting this error.

Just add

```
-ignorewarnings

-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

to proguard-rules.pro

Link: [Stackoverflow Source Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362386/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelea)