# proguard can't find super class [android/os/RemoteException] and [com/google/android/gms/internal/zziv]

Tags: java, android, proguard

I want to generate a signed apk file. I do not understand why I am getting the warning `Can't find common super class of [android/os/RemoteException] (with 5 known super classes) and [com/google/android/gms/internal/zziv] (with 1 known super classes)`
 I read the [manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting) of proguard, but it just states that there is something missing.

> ProGuard (...) need the missing classes (...).

So I've tried to `-keep` these classes as you can see in my proguard file below - no change of the error message.
Furthermore I've tried to `-ignorewarnings` and to keep all classes, public and private, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362386/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelea) - didn't work either, still the same error. If I do not `-ignorewarnings` and no `-dontwarn`, I get the error `org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.`

My current proguard rule file looks like this:

```
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep class android.os.*
-dontwarn android.os.*

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.internal.zziv
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.zziv


-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am seeing the same error, curious how you fixed it.

Comment: Hi Manisha, No unfortunately not, I decided back then not to go with proguard. But If you find a solution, Please write it as an answer!

Comment: Any solution, please post ?