# java.lang.NullPointerException and Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: android, libgdx, proguard

I am trying to export apk and I want to enable Proguard but it throwing below error. I read so many answers and tried but didn't worked. Getting below error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:209)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor319.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:280)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:67)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:178)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)
    ... 1 more
```

this is gradle file of project :

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.6'
        }

    }
    apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'


    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }

    apply plugin: "com.android.application"
    android {
        buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "..."
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    onesignal_app_id               : '',
                    onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
            ]
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0.1"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
        }
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            }

        }
        signingConfigs {

        }


        buildTypes {
            release {

                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                        'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        aaptOptions {
            ignoreAssetsPattern "!assets.zip"
        }
        aaptOptions {
            cruncherEnabled = false
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }


    }

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(':core')
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
        implementation 'ir.tapsell.plus:tapsell-plus-sdk-android:1.1.1'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.7'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        implementation 'com.pushpole.android:pushsdk:1.7.0'

    }

      task copyAndroidNatives() {
        file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86/").mkdirs()

        configurations.getByName("natives").copy().files.each { jar ->
            def outputDir = null
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
            if (outputDir != null) {
                copy {
                    from zipTree(jar)
                    into outputDir
                    include "*.so"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task run(type: Exec) {
        def path
        def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
        if (localProperties.exists()) {
            Properties properties = new Properties()
            localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
                properties.load(instr)
            }
            def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
            if (sdkDir) {
                path = sdkDir
            } else {
                path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
            }
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }

        def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
        commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'rs.pedjaapps.smc.android/rs.pedjaapps.smc.android.AndroidLauncher'
    }
```

proguard file :

[image]

I even done this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41861497/5733853  but didnt correct. and more answer.

Comment: To find the problem, start with a newly generated libgdx project and export the apk. It will work. Now add the changes you made to your project one by one to see when the problem occurs. You've found the cause then.
My bet is on your One Signal SDK or plugin.

Comment: @MrStahlfelge thanks for your time. yes its completely for onesignal implementation how can I correct it. I want to use this.

Comment: That's a question you have to ask the onesignal devs!

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code, make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Posts in which essential text is only present in images are likely to be closed as lacking enough details.